# how to get amazon performance notifications by mws api

Tags: amazon-mws

how to get  amazon performance notifications by Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS)  api ???

seller central >>Performance>>Performance Notifications

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html) and the [report types](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__PerformanceReports).  I don't think there is one specifically for performance notifications like you are looking for, but that would be the place to look first.